# Best practices to manage ROS2 package python dependencies

Tags: python, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What the best practice to manage / install dependencies for ROS2 python package? Installing by `setup.py`? Using system-level or an interpreter in `venv` with `requirements.txt` to install dependencies with `pip` manually? Can colcon trigger installation from pypi on a build stage?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334235/best-practices-to-manage-ros2-package-python-dependencies/) by [khassanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/32429/khassanov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-09-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [khassanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/32429/khassanov/) on 2019-09-30**:
While answers recommends `rosdep`, this one: https://answers.ros.org/question/310728/rosdep-and-ros2/ can help as well.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-09-30**:
That answer is out of date, and all core dependencies are available from debian packages now. And pip dependencies can be resolved by rosdep, they just can't be released into debian paickages.

**Comment by [khassanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/32429/khassanov/) on 2019-10-02**:
Rosdep uses own package registry not connected with [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/). There is a list of Python packages available: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/rosdep/python.yaml. More information is here: https://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rosdep/html/contributing_rules.html

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's strongly recommended to use system dependencies declared in the package.xml file and then standard tools like rosdep can both check and resolve them.

colcon is a build tool. We have specifically separated build and install stages for cleaner separation of concerns as well as to avoid side effects that might have security implications.

A standard practice is to:

1. Download a set of packages into a workspace (using a rosinstall file or repos file and vcstool)
2. Install all dependencies of that workspace (Using rosdep. It will error if anything is unresolved that you might need to maually resolve.)
3. Run your build(with colcon)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2019-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A ROS package must specify its dependencies in the `package.xml` file. Simply because that is the information being used to e.g. release a package with `bloom` into a Debian package.

With that information available you can then use `rosdep` to install the dependencies according to the platform you are on. On Ubuntu it should be Debian packages (otherwise you wouldn't be able to create a Debian package of your package). On other platforms `rosdep` will use `pip`.

`colcon` explicitly does not target to install any dependencies for you (see https://colcon.readthedocs.io/en/released/developer/design.html#explicitly-out-of-scope). It leaves this part to other tools (like `rosdep`).

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1